# Setting minor ticks with log scale axis PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider this MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [width=15cm,height=10cm,
    xmode=log,
    xmin=20, xmax=20000,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    xtick={20,50,100,200,500,1000,5000,10000,20000},
    grid=both,
    ]
    \addplot [
    domain=20:20000, 
    samples=100, 
    ]
    {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want x axis minor ticks to appear at

```
30,40, 
60,70,80,90, 
300,400,
600,700,800,900
2000,3000,4000,
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You could add `extra x ticks={30,40,60,70,80,90,300,400,600,700,800,900,2000,3000,4000},
  extra tick style={grid=minor}` to the axis options but that makes the ticks very crowded.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I added something that adds just the ticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [width=15cm,height=10cm,
    xmode=log,
    xmin=20, xmax=20000,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    xtick={20,50,100,200,500,1000,5000,10000,20000},
    grid=both,
    minor xtick={30,40,60,70,80,90,300,400,600,700,800,900,2000,3000,4000},
    xminorgrids=false
    ]
    \addplot [
    domain=20:20000, 
    samples=100, 
    ]
    {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mike OOPS! Sorry! Fixed it (I hope).